# React usage of aws-amplify generates "require is not defined" error

Tags: reactjs, npm, aws-amplify

Using a simple working React example and then adding this line to the top:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
```

Yields the following error on reload:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

I am using webpack and a simple React render of a component that is straightforward. The packages for aws-amplify were installed using `npm`.

webpack.config.js is as follows:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

var DEV = path.resolve(__dirname, "dev");
var OUTPUT = path.resolve(__dirname, "output");

var config = {
    entry: DEV + "/index.jsx",
    output: {
        path: OUTPUT,
        filename: "myCode.js"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [{
        include: DEV,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      }]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Have you configured webpack to build for target node instead of web? https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/ `require` is a builtin global in node.js, but not on in the browser.

Comment: Edited to show webpack.config.js. I don't have a `target` listed.